# Is it possible to create a subset of Typescript where the result would have a sound type system?

Tags: typescript

Reading this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825 I understand that Typescripts type system is not sound. However if would define a strict subset that

- activates

  - noImplictAny
  - noImplictThis
  - strictNullChecks
- uses only immutable data structures

could the result be a sound subset of Typescript? And if not why? (code examples welcome).

Comment: Not sure if this is really the forum for this, maybe try on GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript

Comment: If you haven't read it already, the [TypeScript handbook on Type Compatibility](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) also has several points on why unsound behaviour is allowed in some situations. Specifically note the sections [Function Parameter Bivariance](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) and [Optional Parameters and Rest Parameters](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#optional-parameters-and-rest-parameters). But I agree with @Titian: Ask the community on GitHub